# loop over characters in input string using awk

Tags: string, for-loop, awk

Believe it or not, I can't find the answer to what I would think would be this very basic question.

In awk, how can I loop over the input string character by character?  Let's say I just wanted to print them out.  Is there an array I can access?  Or do I need to use substr?

Basically, something like:

```
echo "here is a string" | awk '
{ for(i=0; i<[length of input string]; i++) 
    printf [value at index i in array x]; 
}'
```

Frankly, I'm embarrassed.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can convert a string to an array using `split`:

```
echo "here is a string" | awk '
{ 
  split($0, chars, "")
  for (i=1; i <= length($0); i++) {
    printf("%s\n", chars[i])
  }
}'
```

This prints the characters vertically, one per line.

Comment: actually, length() is a gawk extension AFAIK, it doesn't work on pure awk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720898/illegal-reference-to-an-array-in-awk-i-am-having-trouble-figuring-out-awk

Comment: @vaxquis I'm not sure what you mean by "pure" awk, but `length` is in POSIX. The gawk extension is in applying to arrays instead of strings. Fortunately, we can just switch `length(chars)` to `length($0)`.

Comment: "pure" awk in the sense of "not any extended awk"... and yes, I meant this usage of length(); also, you can use "len = split(...)" and later "i<=len" with the same result.

Comment: one more question - this obviously ignores whitespaces in the input - is there any way to split the data so that I actually *know* where the whitespaces were? or do I have to parse each 'record' (line) separately to do that?

Answer (score 24):

By default in `awk` the `Field Separator (FS)` is `space` or `tabs`. Since you mentioned you wanted to loop over each character and not word, we will have to redefine the FS to nothing. Something like this -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "here is a string" | awk -v FS="" '
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "Character "i": " $i"\n"}' 
Character 1: h
Character 2: e
Character 3: r
Character 4: e
Character 5:  
Character 6: i
Character 7: s
Character 8:  
Character 9: a
Character 10:  
Character 11: s
Character 12: t
Character 13: r
Character 14: i
Character 15: n
Character 16: g
```

Comment: hm. actually, it works when FS is set in the code, but in a bit different way... (eg. first line is not parsed) Any ideas why?

Comment: It's because the first line is already read before with default FS.

Comment: @vaxquis You have to do it in BEGIN: `'BEGIN {FS="";}'`

Comment: @vaxquis Setting the `FS` outside the code or in `BEGIN` is one and the same thing. `BEGIN` block is read only once before the first line of input is read.

Comment: Note that the behavior of an empty `FS` in many implementations of awk is undefined: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044272/gawk-fs-to-split-record-into-individual-characters

Answer (score 8):

Not all awk implementations support the above solutions.
In that case you could use *substr*:

```
echo here is a string | awk '{
  for (i=0; ++i <= length($0);) 
    printf "%s\n", substr($0, i, 1)
  }'
```

P.S. In some *awk* implementations length without arguments defaults to *$0*, 
i.e. *length* and *length($0)* are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

if you have gawk:

```
awk '$0=gensub(/(.)/,"\\1\n","g")' file
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "I am a String"|awk '$0=gensub(/(.)/,"\\1\n","g")'
I

a
m

a

S
t
r
i
n
g
```

Comment: is there a way to do something with each character using this method or is it just reformatting the string?

Comment: it can "do something with each char". but it depends what is "something"