# Making horizontal String vertical shell or awk

Tags: string, shell, awk, vertical-alignment, alignment

I have a string

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

I would like it to print.

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
```

ie horizontal, no editing between characters to vertical.  Bonus points for how to put a number next to each one with a single line.  It'd be nice if this were an awk or shell script, but I am open to learning new things. :)  Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563745/loop-over-characters-in-input-string-using-awk

Comment: thanks, I also figured this out on my own after a lot of messing.

Comment: @EliRose - the answer accepted in the question you reference has errors on almost every line, all of then newbie mistakes. You shouldn't provide it as a reference.

Comment: @user2348290 - the "solution" you figured out does not produce the output you requested (it adds an extra line) and will fail on some systems so I wouldn't use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to convert a string to one-char-per-line, you just need to tell awk that each input character is a separate field and that each output field should be separated by a newline and then recompile each record by assigning a field to itself:

```
awk -v FS= -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1'
```

e.g.:

```
$ echo "ABCDEFGHIJ" | awk -v FS= -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1'
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
```

and if you want field numbers next to each character, see @Kent's solution or pipe to `cat -n`.

The sed solution you posted is non-portable and will fail with some seds on some OSs, and it will add an undesirable blank line to the end of your sed output which will then become a trailing line number after your pipe to `cat -n` so it's not a good alternative. You should accept @Kent's answer.

Answer (score 3):

awk one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print i,$i}'
```

test :

```
kent$  echo "ABCDEF"|awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print i,$i}'                                                                                                       
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
6 F
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this one out on my own with sed.

```
 sed 's/./&\n/g' horiz.txt > vert.txt
```

Comment: added cat -n to add the number that I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

One more awk

```
echo "ABCDEFGHIJ" | awk '{gsub(/./,"&\n")}1'
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
```

Comment: That has the same problem that the similar posted sed scripts have in that it will add a trailing blank line to the end of the output.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\B/\n/g' <<<ABCDEFGHIJ
```

for line numbers:

```
sed 's/\B/\n/g' <<<ABCDEFGHIJ | sed = | sed 'N;y/\n/ /'
```

or:

```
sed 's/\B/\n/g' <<<ABCDEFGHIJ | cat -n
```