# Iterate over list of known characters

Tags: loops, awk, gawk

To iterate over a list of characters that are known at the time of writing the program (in this example, the characters are "X", "Y", "Z"):

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    c = substr("XYZ", i, 1)
    # do something with the character
}
```

**Question:** *Is there a more awk-y way of doing this?* Note that this is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563745/loop-over-characters-in-input-string-using-awk), as the characters I want to iterate over are not a part of the input.

To put it in context, I need to count the occurences of X, Y and Z on a particular position in a line over all lines. The input should consist only of X, Y and Zs on lines of the same length:

```
$ cat input.txt
XYXXXYZZYXY
XXXYYYZYYZY
YZZZZYZZXZZ
XXZXXYYZXZY

$ foo.awk < input.txt
X 3 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 1 0
Y 1 1 0 1 1 4 1 1 2 0 3
Z 0 1 2 1 1 0 3 3 0 3 1
```

This is `foo.awk` at the moment:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = ""
}
NR == 1 {
    len = NF
}
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        ++profile[$i][i]
}
END {
    for (c = 1; c <= 3; ++c) {
        char = substr("XYZ", c, 1)
        printf "%s", char
        for (i = 1; i <= len; ++i)
            printf " %d", profile[char][i]
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

I have not used awk before so probably my whole approach is totally wrong.

Comment: It would help a lot with an example text and what to get out of it.

Comment: @Jotne You are of course right, I added it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script looks good.  Here is a version that illustrates some slight variations in style:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = ""
    split("XYZ",chars,"")
}
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        ++profile[$i,i]
}
END {
    for (c=1;c in chars;c++) {
        printf "%s", chars[c]
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
            printf " %d", profile[chars[c],i]
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

The statement `split("XYZ",chars,"")` creates an array `chars` that has your letters in it.  That way, the characters can be referred to by subscript.

Your script uses multidimensional arrays which is a GNU extension.  In the script above, I used the standard `awk` method for getting the same result.  (The setting is `FS=""` also a GNU extension.)

Lastly, the outer `for` loop in `END` was changed to scan over the array indices with `for (c=1;c in chars;c++) ...`.  This has the advantage of working even if you change the number of elements in `chars`.  The disadvantage is that, unless we complicate the code, `awk` does not guarantee that the indices come out in order.

Comment: Thank you! As far as the `for (c in chars)`, this is what I had, before I realized that it doesn't necessarily iterate in the initial order. So I guess it must be `for (i = 1; i <= length; ++i)`.

Comment: And not only are multidimensional arrays an extension, they are new enough not to be in the version of gawk installed on a server I have to use....

Comment: +1 FYI setting `FS = ""` is also a gawk extension, the behavior is unspecified by POSIX. The `len` variable and associated `NR==1` block isn't necessary as `NF` will be set in the `END` section to it's value on the last read line so you can just loop to `NF` instead of to `len`. You also don't need the 3rd arg to `split()` since what you're using is the same as `FS`.

Comment: @Boris consider `for (i = 1; i in chars; ++i)` instead of `for (i = 1; i <= length; ++i)`. `length` with no args is a gawk extension to provide the length of the current input record ($0), not the length of the array you're interested in. length(array) returning the number of entries in an array is also a gawk extension. $0 being set in the END section is ALSO a gawk extension. The `in` operator is standard awk.

Comment: @EdMorton the `i <= length` in the for loop was not meant to be actual code; sorry for being unclear. However, `for (i = 1; i in chars; ++i)` is much better anyway and exactly what I need! Thank you, and for the other tips, too!

Comment: @EdMorton I incorporated your improvements into the answer.